# ROS Answers SE migration: About bash

Tags: ros, bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have given the cmd like this cd ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
bash: cd: /home/abi/fuerte_workspace/sandbox: No such file or directory
how can i recover this error always i'm getting error in my bash file

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51486/about-bash/) by [Abinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3901/abinaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2013-01-04**:
Have you modified your `~/.bashrc` file? If yes, can you please share your modifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That error results from a directory not being in existence. You can create it:

```
mkdir ~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
```

If it exists, make sure you are in the right user account. Maybe update your post with the end of your ~/.bashrc file? It is highly unlikely that this error is the result of that file, however.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2013-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1